# Erlang- maps:iterator/1 & maps:next/1 deprecated?

Tags: erlang

i've been trying to iterate through a map i've made:

```
getMinTreeHeight(TreeList,TreeMap) -> lists:foreach(fun(X) -> TreeMap#{X => getTreeHeight(X)} end, TreeList),
                                      Iter = maps:iterator(TreeMap),
                                      findMin(Iter,infinity,key).

findMin(Iterator,Min,Key) -> case maps:next(Iterator) of
                                none -> Key;
                                {K,V,I} -> if
                                             V < Min -> findMin(I,V,K) ;
                                             true -> findMin(I,Min,Key)
                                           end
                             end.
```

these are the 2 functions, in the upper function i go through each value in the list and do something on it, then i insert the pair into a map. finally i make an iterator (which appears in the erlang.org docs).
in the 2nd function i just iterate the map using maps:next, with a given iterator.
when i try to compile my module it tells me that iterator/1 and next/1 are undefined. anyone know if im using them correctly? or if they are still valid functions?
im using erlang/OTP20 if its relevant

Answer (score 0):

a.erl:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").

getTreeHeight(X) ->
    X.

getMinTreeHeight(TreeList,TreeMap) -> lists:foreach(fun(X) -> TreeMap#{X => getTreeHeight(X)} end, TreeList),
                                      Iter = maps:iterator(TreeMap),
                                      findMin(Iter,infinity,key).

findMin(Iterator,Min,Key) -> case maps:next(Iterator) of
                                none -> Key;
                                {K,V,I} -> if
                                             V < Min -> findMin(I,V,K) ;
                                             true -> findMin(I,Min,Key)
                                           end
                             end.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(a).
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

3>
```

Comment: Now it's compiling, though when trying to test the function, when i call the function, getMinTreeheight i still get an exception error saying the functions (iterator) is undefined. got any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around - `maps:iterator/1` and `maps:next/1` were introduced in Erlang/OTP 21.0, so that's why you're unable to call them from release 20.

You can tell by looking at [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#iterator-1): to the right of the function signature it shows "OTP 21.0" to indicate which release that function was introduced in.

Comment: thank you! didn't notice that in the documentation it said it was from version 21, in fact i thought i had read yesterday that it was from OTP 17. now its running and compiling.